# Facebook login button not displayed

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

This is the rendered login page for the tutorial [here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website%20%28With%20Javascript%20SDK%29&referringTitle=Documentation)
The login button does not appear in IE9. Why? 
I must mention that I run it in IIS7 not IIS express, if it metters

    
    
        Login

```
<h2>Login using Facebook</h2>

<div>
    <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
</div>

<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    FB.init({
        appId: '120795328019415', cookie: true,
        status: true, xfbml: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
</script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the site url in your app settings matches exactly. The redirect URL needs to be valid as well. It sould point to a URL on your site domain.